# glossary files can not be loaded

Tags: dita-ot

I am trying to use glossaries in DITA OT 2.2

I am trying to follow the instructions found at
http://idratherbewriting.com/acronyms_and_glossary/

I am getting the following message:

```
[gen-list] Processing file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/frontmatter/trademarks.dita
[gen-list] Processing file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/frontmatter/preface.dita
[gen-list] Processing file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/chapters/courseauthoringstandards.dita
[gen-list] Processing file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/concepts/AICCintro.dita
[gen-list] Processing file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/chapters/introduction.dita
[gen-list] Processing file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/glossary/aicc.dita
[gen-list] Processing file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/glossary/opentoolkit.dita
[gen-list] Processing file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/glossary/opentoolkitplugin.dita
[gen-list] [DOTX008E][ERROR] File 'file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/glossary/aicc.dita' does not exist or cannot be loaded.
[gen-list] [DOTX008E][ERROR] File 'file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/glossary/opentoolkit.dita' does not exist or cannot be loaded.
[gen-list] [DOTX008E][ERROR] File 'file:/C:/RAMDrive/build/target/dita/resources/glossary/opentoolkitplugin.dita' does not exist or cannot be loaded.
[gen-list] Serializing job specification
```

The files are there.

```
C:\RAMDrive\build\target\dita\resources\glossary>dir
Volume in drive C is S3A9477D002
 Volume Serial Number is 1E29-E1A2

 Directory of C:\RAMDrive\build\target\dita\resources\glossary

26/01/2016  03:04 PM    <DIR>          .
26/01/2016  03:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
27/01/2016  01:33 AM             1,020 aicc.dita
27/01/2016  01:33 AM               699 opentoolkit.dita
27/01/2016  01:33 AM               630 opentoolkitplugin.dita
               3 File(s)          2,349 bytes
              2 Dir(s)     648,265,728 bytes free
```

What else should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please create and upload a ZIP file of your project (or a subset of your project) to reproduce the error? Unfortunately the output of the toolkit is not enough to answer your question.

**UPDATE**

Change the DOCTYPE of the files:

- `aicc.dita`
- `opentoolkit.dita`
- `opentoolkitplugin.dita`

from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glossentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA GLOSSARY//EN"
"../../dtd/glossentry.dtd">
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glossentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Glossary//EN" "glossary.dtd">
```

You do not need to use a relative path to the `glossary.dtd`, just use its filename.

Comment: http://www.artifact-software.com/DITA/LearningAdministratorCompanion.zip is the entire Eclipse project.
To run it, you will probably need to create directories c:\RAMDrive\build and c:\RAMDrive\temp

Answer (score 0):

The public identifier is case sensitive. So you should rewrite:

```
<!DOCTYPE glossentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA GLOSSARY//EN"
"../../dtd/glossentry.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE glossentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Glossary//EN"
"../../dtd/glossentry.dtd">
```

This will solve your problem.